# extract data from Pdf using Web harvesting

Tags: webharvest

How can i extract data from PDF using Web Harvesting? I am getting all the relevant PDFs url in a page but i am not been able to extract data out of those Pdf.I am using Web Harvest version 2.0 for extracting the Pdfs url. Please help.

how will i incorporate pdfcommand in web harvesting to get the text? Is there any other way to do without running any batch file?

Answer (score 0):

I think web harvest is not sufficient for this. You should use WGET and pdfbox to get your result. First download all the PDF through your URL into a folder with the help of WGET or Web harvest itself. Then run pdfbox command to get text from PDFs. You may get some knowledge on pdfbox from URL http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandline/. You can also create a batch file to run these things in order.